# Elastic Beanstalk Prevent Files Overwriting

Tags: wordpress, git, caching, amazon-web-services

So a little background i am trying to setup a local staging and production environment using Elastic Beanstalk and Wordpress.

So i have a local environment setup with git and i have the following in the

```
.gitignore.
#################
## WordPress
#################
.git-rewrite/
local-config.php
.elasticbeanstalk/
Linux/
```

I have the ELB CLI installed and i can run

```
git aws.push
```

and it deploys to staging and i can also run.

```
git aws.push --environment main-env-production
```

Works great but here is my frustration i have W3 Total Cache plugin installed locally and i dont have memcached installed on my local MAMP setup.

Each setup is using a different database i have two RDS setups one for staging and one for production.

I setup all my cache information within the total cache plugin on my staging environment i setup object cache with memcached and enter my elastic cache node url.

But everytime i run aws.push it seems to overwrite all my settings which as you can understand is really annoying can anyone explain why it might be doing this?

Do i have to have my local version completely mirror the staging and production environments how do you only version certain folders with beanstalk is this even possible.

Thanks really want to have a setup that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you are using a very old version of the EB CLI. But that’s irrelevant to your problem/question.

> how do you only version certain folders with beanstalk is this even possible?

No, this is not possible. Let me explain what beanstalk is doing.

Elastic Beanstalk stores your files in a certain directory, lets call it `/app/` for brevity. Everytime you deploy (aws.push) EB deletes the entire directory `/app/` and replaces it with the new version of your code.

Basically, there is no concept of versioning on Elastic Beanstalk. `aws.push` is a separate service that takes your versioned files, builds a full code zip file, and deploys it to elastic beanstalk.